# PyCharm type hinting: return type not detected

Tags: python, properties, pycharm

I want to add type hinting to PyCharm, but PyCharm does not detect the return type if I use `cached_property` instead of `property`.

```
class MyClass(object):

    #@cached_property # does not work
    @property         # works
    def foo_client(self):
        '''
        @rtype foo.Client
        '''
        return client_getter(...)
```

Usage:

```
my_class = MyClass()
my_class.foo_client.HERE_I_WANT_AUTOCOMPLETE
```

I use `cached-property==1.1.0` and PyCharm 4.5.

Comment: It does seem to be copying the `__doc__` through appropriately: https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property/blob/master/cached_property.py#L20 Not sure whether this is PyCharm's fault or `cached-property`'s, but it's not at all clear what answer you're expecting here.

Comment: A note to those who casted close votes: This is a *completely* understandable problem. It occurs, and to those who actually know how to use the tool, this question makes perfect sense. So, although I do understand that *most* of you have good intentions in casting a close vote, it is not warranted. To the OP: Try not using EAP builds, they are buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using an EAP build, this problem can have several solutions.

1. Revert back to the old PyCharm. EAP builds are buggy and often have problems with older features. This might actually be the case since PyCharm is trying to add support for type hinting (Python 3.5) and so you might have a problem with the code completion that you're getting.
2. The format in which you're writing your stubs is called Epytype, and is almost never used anywhere, so it can often fail to work. I would suggest using reStructuredText instead. Just change the document format from "Eypdoc/Epytype" to reStructuredText inside of Python Integrated Tools > Docstrings. This will most likely solve the problem.
3. If points 1 and 2 fail. Then this is a genuine bug and I suggest that you report it at youtrack.jetbrains.